# Overriding operator

Tags: c++, overriding, overloading, new-operator

anybody me about constructor overriding..

i have this

```
void  operator delete(void*) {}

void  operator delete(void* p, void*) {}
```

in my class.. that looks like overloading(same function name and return type but different parameter list) but its overriding .. how its overriding..

anyone an explain me these two lines function.

Comment: have u been able to call the 2nd overload using delete expression?

Comment: its not overloading.. its overrding.. no actually i did not understand these two function

Comment: One question: why? To elaborate; what are you trying to achieve? If you want special behaviour when your class is deallocated, write a destructor instead.

Comment: You can't ever override `operator delete` because `operator delete` is always `static` whether explicitly declared so or not. Overriding only applies to `virtual` functions.

Comment: @Charles: `operator delete` is kind of a sort of, like, :-), exception to that general rule. For polymorphic statically known class it's looked up in the most derived (dynamic) class. But I forget the details; I'd look it up if I needed to do this stuff. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

```
void  operator delete(void*) {}
void  operator delete(void* p, void*) {}
```

These are custom deallocation functions. A deallocation function is called via a `delete`expression. E.g.

```
YourClass* p = new YourClass();    // Allocates memory & calls constructor
// ... whatever, then
delete p;                          // Calls destructor & deallocates memory
```

For your class the `delete` expression in the last line above would first call the destructor, and then it would call the single `void*` argument deallocation function that the class defines, the first of your two functions, *if* that deallocation is accessible.

However, it might be that the deallocation function is declared as `private` or `protected`, for the purpose of making it inaccessible. In the first case a `delete` expression outside the class' own code won't compile (inaccessible deallocation function). And if so then that may be the whole point  --  or, don't be surprised if there's no point at all.

By the way, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/). It's apparently the least bad free introduction to C++ on the net. Bruce Eckel's e-book ["Thinking in C++"](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) is also free, but it has some errors and misinformation (it used to be the other way around though, the tutorial at cplusplus.com used to be very bad, once).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1 Thinking in C++ is a good book, esp. for anyone who knows a bit about programming in the first place. If you know about some errors in the book I bet Eckel would be pleased if you pointed them out for him.

Comment: @daramarak I mentioned that about errors because the good Bruce has not fixed reported errors, so, people have asked the same questions again and again over the years. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

They're overloading the delete operator, and the second one is using "placement delete".  Placement new/delete are a hack so that you can have C++ constructors initialize the class on top of memory you provide (instead of ::new), and possibly with additional arguments like you see here.  Google can fill you in with the gory details.

Comment: This is a nasty corner of C++.  Usually when you call new and delete, you'll be using the C++ compiler's implementation to actually allocate and free the memory.  C++ lets you override this behavior though, and you can declare your own versions of new and delete.  If you (or another author) do this, you can do all kinds of crazy (and sometimes useful) things, and you can add additional arguments to the calls to new and delete.  This topic is a little deeper than I can go into right now, but Google for "placement new" and "placement delete", and you'll find a lot of information.

Comment: I really wouldn't describe them as a "hack", in my opinion.  They're operators that can be overloaded and customized like any other operator.  How is this a "hack"?

Comment: @Moo-Juice, I used to be a proud C++ language lawyer, and once I might have agreed with you that this is some sort of useful feature, but I've seen the mess that good programmers make from this kind of thing, and I now just think it's a klugy hack that might be useful in some circumstances but which should generally be avoided.  After you spend a significant amount of time working with other programmers who stumble over this kind of thing, and get stuck cleaning up the messes they make, you might agree.

Answer (score 0):

These are operator delete overloading and are called when `delete` is invoked on the object. From 3.7.3.2 (Deallocation functions) :

> Each deallocation function shall return void and its first parameter shall be void*. A deallocation function
>   can have more than one parameter. **If a class T has a member deallocation function named operator
>   delete with exactly one parameter, then that function is a usual (non-placement) deallocation function**. If
>   class T does not declare such an operator delete but does declare a member deallocation function
>   named operator delete with exactly two parameters, the second of which has type std::size_t
>   (18.1), then this function is a usual deallocation function.

And in 12.5 Free store :

> When a delete-expression is executed, the selected deallocation function shall be called with the address of
>   **the block of storage to be reclaimed as its first argument and (if the two-parameter style is used) the size of
>   the block as its second argument**.

I'm not sure your second function can ever be called as it is not a 'usual deallocation function'.

Comment: It can be called manually, or it can be called by a `new` expression that invoked the corresponding placement new, if the constructor throws. That's the only case where a placement delete is invoked automatically. Microsoft once hit on the "smart" idea of using placement new to help debugging, but forgot to define the corresponding placement delete. With result that memory was leaked but only in debug builds... :-) It was one of most infamous MFC bugs. Cheers,